# Reference module export by string

Tags: typescript

I am attempting to dynamically instance a class from a module via string.

Say I have `./src/main.ts`, `./src/role/index.ts`, and `./src/role/role<n>.ts`

Within `./src/role/index.ts`:

```
export * from './role1.ts'
export * from './role2.ts'
```

And an example role `./src/role/role1.ts`

```
export class Role1 {
    constructor() { }
}
```

And then from my main, i want to do something like

```
import * as Roles from './role'
function load_role(to_load: string) {
    for(let role in Roles) {
       if(role == to_load) // e.g. Role1
          return Roles[role]()
    }
}
```

To avoid something unwieldly such as:

```
import * as Roles from './role'
function load_role(to_load: string) {
    if(to_load == 'Role1')
        return Roles.Role1()
    else if(to_load == 'Role<n>')
        return Roles.Role<n>()
}
```

But I cannot reference the Roles module by string, is this possible?

Comment: can you share content of roleN.ts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest thing you can probably do is type `to_load` as a union of [string literals](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#string-literal-types):

```
function load_role(to_load: "Role1" | "Role2") {
    for(let role in Roles) {
        if (role == to_load) // e.g. Role1
            return Roles[to_load]();
    }
}
```

Or if you are OK to lose static typing, then cast it to `any`:

```
function load_role(to_load: string) {
    if ((Roles as any)[to_load]) {
        (Roles as any)[to_load]();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> But I cannot reference the Roles module by string, is this possible?

No. ES6 modules are designed for static safety and you are not allowed to use *string* indexers into the module.